# Exist a way to show ion a flutter app a svg image with <style> tag?

Tags: flutter, svg

I'm facing the following problem: I get througth a 3rd party endpoint a svg image with  tag. That image must be shown on a flutter app.  The library I've been using flutter_svg, gives me the following error:The  element is not implemented in this library
How can I solve or workaround this problem?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/105) might give you some hint